# VPN Server in Windows Server: 2-factor with google authenticator or similar?

Tags: windows, vpn

We would like to use windows server as a vpn server for ipsec vpn for remote laptop users.

We would like to require 2 factor auth, so these users would present their windows credentials, and then need to enter a pseudo random #, for example using google authenticator on a phone.

Is this possible, and if so where are docs/pieces?

(And if not in win2012-R2, coming in win2016?)